# installing nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia

I have just installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Assus 556-UX notebook with Nvidia 930MX card. I have noticed that in the 'details' section in 'Settings' it still says the graphic card is the intel's on-board card, so I wanted to install the nvidia driver. 
I am new to linux, what is the best way of doing this?

thank you

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times on AskUbuntu. For example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/507298/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-nvidia-drivers-now and

Answer (score 0):

I usually install the Nvidia drivers from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

(then reboot)

You should be able to switch between your Nvidia dGPU and Intel iGPU using:

```
$ sudo prime-select [nvidia|intel]
```

You can query which GPU is in use using:

```
$ prime-select query
```

**NOTE:** I have had huge headaches with Nvidia drivers lately, namely:

- The Nvidia GPU doesn't power down after switching to the Intel iGPU.
- Lots and lots of "micro-stutter" when scrolling/dragging windows.

I found a "fix" (workaround?) for my particular laptop in regards to the first issue:

- Edit `/etc/default/grub` after switching to the iGPU.
- Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.pm=1"`
- Remove the `nouveau.pm=1`
- From the terminal, run: `$ sudo update-grub`

I haven't been able to find a fix for the "micro-stutters", but this issue is subjective and will bother some users more than others (I'm in the former group, it bothers me a lot - so much so that I have uninstalled the proprietary Nvidia drivers and am currently using the Nouveau drivers, which are much "smoother" for most desktop functions).